# KendoUI ListView Double Click Selected Item

Tags: listview, kendo-ui

I am attempting to get the Name from the template of a KendoUI ListItem after the user double clicks.
I cannot seem to find a way to get the value of the selected item.  The alert is coming back as undefined.

```
   <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
       <div class="machineInstances">
               #:Name# [#:Environment#] #:Description#
        </div>
    </script>

  $("#listView").kendoListView({
      dataSource: dataSource,
      selectable: "single"
      , dataBound: setItemDoubleClickEvent
      , template: kendo.template($("#template").html())

   });

  function setItemDoubleClickEvent() {
      var items = $(".machineInstances");
      items.dblclick(function () {
              $("#menuInstances").click();
              var selected = $("#listView").data("kendoListView").select();
              alert(selected.Name);
               alert("Double Click!");
              });
      }
```

Thank you,

Drew

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a Kendo UI ListView, `select` does not return the item but the HTML. You should use `index()` for getting the index of the element selected and the `dataSource.view()` for retrieving current displayed elements.

Your code should be:

```
function setItemDoubleClickEvent() {
    var items = $(".machineInstances");
    items.dblclick(function () {
        $("#menuInstances").click();
        var listView = $("#listView").data("kendoListView");
        var idx = listView.select().index();
        var item = listView.dataSource.view()[idx];
        alert(item.Name);
        alert("Double Click!");
    });
}
```

But I would recommend simplifying the code to:

```
function setItemDoubleClickEvent() {
    $(".machineInstances").on("dblclick", function () {
        var listView = $("#listView").data("kendoListView");
        var idx = $(this).index();
        var item = listView.dataSource.view()[idx];
        alert(item.Name);
        alert("Double Click!");
    });
}
```

Or using a completely different strategy for getting the same result:

```
var listView = $("#listView").data("kendoListView");
function setItemDoubleClickEvent() {
    $(".machineInstances", listView).on("dblclick", function () {
        var uid = $(this).data("uid");
        var item = listView.dataSource.getByUid(uid);
        alert(item.Name);
        alert("Double Click!");
    });
}
```

Where I get the `uid` of the double-clicked element and then retrieve the item data using `getByUid`.

Also setting listView outside prevents having to compute it each time we execute the function.

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/3wQaK/